# change resolution of video using ffmpeg

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I have a folder that contains videos with a resolution of 1080 and different bitrates. I am trying to change their resolution to 480 and using the following code:

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg.exe','-i', pname1,'-vf', 'scale=-1:480,setsar=1:1','-c:v','libx264','-pix_fmt' ,'yuv420p','-b:v', str(cnt)+'K', '-bufsize', str(cnt)+'K' ,'-minrate', str(cnt)+'K','-maxrate', str(cnt)+'K', '-x264opts','keyint=60:min-keyint=60','-preset', 'veryfast', '-profile:v', 'high', '-f', 'hls', '-hls_time', '2', '-hls_list_size','0', pname2])
```

but it produces noting in the related filename (`pname2`). it also shows no error.
what is the problem and how can I change the resolution to 480?

Comment: `pname2` must be the output filename not folder

Comment: yes all the things are right. this the name of the filename

Comment: When I change 480 to other values such as 360, 720 the code works and has output!!

Comment: try `scale=-2:480`